# SQL - UNION vs NULL functions. Which is better?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables: ACCT, PERS, ORG. Each ACCT is owned by either a PERS or ORG. The PERS and ORG tables are very similar and so are all of their child tables, but all PERS and ORG data is separate.

I'm writing a query to get PERS and ORG information for each account in ACCT and I'm curious what the best method of combining the information is. Should I use a series of left joins and NULL functions to fill in the blanks, or should I write the queries separately and use UNION to combine?

I've already written separate queries for PERS ACCT's and another for ORG ACCT's and plan on using UNION. My question more pertains to best practice in the future.

I'm expecting both to give me my desired my results, but I want to find the most efficient method both in development time and run time.

EDIT: Sample Table Data

ACCT Table:

```
+---------+---------+--------------+-------------+
| ACCTNBR | ACCTTYP | OWNERPERSNBR | OWNERORGNBR |
+---------+---------+--------------+-------------+
|  555001 | abc     |         3010 |             |
|  555002 | abc     |              |        2255 |
|  555003 | tre     |         5125 |             |
|  555004 | tre     |         4485 |             |
|  555005 | dsa     |              |        6785 |
+---------+---------+--------------+-------------+
```

PERS Table:

```
+---------+--------------+---------------+----------+-------+
| PERSNBR |    PHONE     |    STREET     |   CITY   | STATE |
+---------+--------------+---------------+----------+-------+
|    3010 | 555-555-5555 | 1234 Main St  | New York | NY    |
|    5125 | 555-555-5555 | 1234 State St | New York | NY    |
|    4485 | 555-555-5555 | 6542 Vine St  | New York | NY    |
+---------+--------------+---------------+----------+-------+
```

ORG Table:

```
+--------+--------------+--------------+----------+-------+
| ORGNBR |    PHONE     |    STREET    |   CITY   | STATE |
+--------+--------------+--------------+----------+-------+
|   2255 | 222-222-2222 | 1000 Main St | New York | NY    |
|   6785 | 333-333-3333 | 400 4th St   | New York | NY    |
+--------+--------------+--------------+----------+-------+
```

Desired Output:

```
+---------+---------+--------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+----------+-------+
| ACCTNBR | ACCTTYP | OWNERPERSNBR | OWNERORGNBR |    PHONE     |    STREET     |   CITY   | STATE |
+---------+---------+--------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+----------+-------+
|  555001 | abc     |         3010 |             | 555-555-5555 | 1234 Main St  | New York | NY    |
|  555002 | abc     |              |        2255 | 222-222-2222 | 1000 Main St  | New York | NY    |
|  555003 | tre     |         5125 |             | 555-555-5555 | 1234 State St | New York | NY    |
|  555004 | tre     |         4485 |             | 555-555-5555 | 6542 Vine St  | New York | NY    |
|  555005 | dsa     |              |        6785 | 333-333-3333 | 400 4th St    | New York | NY    |
+---------+---------+--------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+----------+-------+
```

Query Option 1: Write 2 queries and use UNION to combine them:

```
select a.acctnbr, a.accttyp, a.ownerpersnbr, a.ownerorgnbr, p.phone, p.street, p.city, p.state
from acct a 
inner join pers p on p.persnbr = a.ownerpersnbr

UNION

select a.acctnbr, a.accttyp, a.ownerpersnbr, a.ownerorgnbr, o.phone, o.street, o.city, o.state
from acct a
inner join org o on o.orgnbr = a.ownerorgnbr
```

Option 2: Use NVL() or Coalesce to return a single data set:

```
SELECT a.acctnbr,
a.accttyp,
NVL(a.ownerpersnbr, a.ownerorgnbr) Owner,
NVL(p.phone, o.phone) Phone,
NVL(p.street, o.street) Street,
NVL(p.city, o.city) City,
NVL(p.state, o.state) State

FROM
acct a
LEFT JOIN pers p on p.persnbr = a.ownerpersnbr
LEFT JOIN org o on o.orgnbr = a.ownerorgnbr
```

There are way more fields in each of the 3 tables as well as many more PERS and ORG tables in my actual query. Is one way better (faster, more efficient) than another?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  As for terminology, neither `UNION` nor `NULL` are "functions".  The former is a set operator, the latter a constant.

Comment: Do you mean either NVL or Coalesce instead of NULL functions?

Comment: @GordonLinoff see edits. I am referring to NULL functions like Coalesce, NVL, or the union operator.

Answer (score 2):

That depends, on what you consider "better".

Assuming, that you will always want to pull all rows from `ACCT` table, I'd say to go for the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and no `UNION`. (If using `UNION`, then rather go for `UNION ALL` variant.)

**EDIT**: As you've already shown your queries, mine is no longer required, and did not match your structures. Removing this part.

Why `LEFT JOIN`? Because with `UNION` you'd have to go through `ACCT` twice, based on "parent" criteria (whether separate or done `INNER JOIN` criteria), while with plain `LEFT OUTER JOIN` you'll probably get just one pass through `ACCT`. In both cases, rows from "parents" will most probably be accessed based on primary keys.

As you are probably considering performance, when looking for "better", as always: Test your queries and look at the execution plans with adequate and fresh database statistics in place, as depending on the data "layout" (histograms, etc.) the "better" may be something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand what a Union does versus a join statement.   A union takes the records from multiple tables, generally similar or the same structure and combines them into a single resultset.   It is not meant to combine multiple dissimilar tables.

What I am seeing is that you have two tables PERS and ORG with some of the same data in it.  In this case I suggest you union those two tables and then join to ACCT to get the sample output.

In this case to get the output as you have shown you would want to use Outer joins so that you don't drop any records without a match.   That will give you nulls in some places but most of the time that is what you want.   It is much easier to filter those out later.

Very rough sample code.

```
SELECT a.*, b.* 
from Acct as a
FULL OUTER JOIN ( 
   Select * from PERS UNION Select * from ORG
      ) as b
ON a.ID = b.ID
```